# Count ISNULL convert to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT   
    COUNT(ISNULL(TRY_CAST(item AS nvarchar), 'Unknown')) AS [col], 
    item
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    item
```

And I get this result:

```
col item
---------
2   NULL
1   100
```

Not sure why `NULL` won't change to 'Unknown'.

Can you point out the wrong query? Thank you

Comment: (a) You're grouping by `item`, not `ISNULL(item, 'Unknown')` (b) `COUNT()` will return 1 for every row within each group, regardless of the outcome of `isnull/try_cast` etc., so that's not where you want `COUNT()` (c) [never cast as `nvarchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you will get unexpected truncation, and this could make your counts wrong (at best).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select statement is off, and you presumably wanted this:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_CAST(item AS nvarchar), 'Unknown') AS item, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM table1
GROUP BY ISNULL(TRY_CAST(item AS nvarchar), 'Unknown');
```

Comment: then the count is wrong, the unknow count 0.Tthe unknown should count 2

Comment: @user1203397 AFAIK `COUNT(*)` _will_ count everything regardless of `NULL`.  The alternative would be to use `COUNT(item)`, but I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Ah, I see. Got it. Thank you and thanks to Aarron for the tip.